# App rejected due to launch crash

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, app-store-connect, ipv6

Yesterday I have submitted binary to iTunes. And they rejected the binary due to launch crash. Also they rejected due to iPv6. I have tested my app on iPv6 network and its working fine. I don't know why this is happening.

Here is the crash report:

```
Version:             11 (2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.identifier


Date/Time:           2017-07-05 10:28:28.1687 -0700
Launch Time:         2017-07-05 10:28:08.0087 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F89)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018559f224 0x18559e000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018559f09c 0x18559e000 + 4252
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185490ee4 0x185479000 + 98020
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001854912e8 0x185479000 + 99048
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001856b8ee0 0x1856b2000 + 28384
5   Security                        0x00000001869dbe44 0x1869b1000 + 175684
6   Security                        0x00000001869dc114 0x1869b1000 + 176404
7   Security                        0x0000000186a016ec 0x1869b1000 + 329452
8   Security                        0x0000000186a03730 0x1869b1000 + 337712
9   Security                        0x0000000186a0078c 0x1869b1000 + 325516
10  Security                        0x0000000186a01424 0x1869b1000 + 328740
11  Security                        0x0000000186a0122c 0x1869b1000 + 328236
12  Security                        0x00000001869ffc3c 0x1869b1000 + 322620
13  Security                        0x0000000186a00d58 0x1869b1000 + 327000
14  APPNAME                     0x0000000100112cf0 0x1000c8000 + 306416
15  APPNAME                     0x0000000100222898 0x1000c8000 + 1419416
16  APPNAME                     0x00000001002225a8 0x1000c8000 + 1418664
17  APPNAME                     0x0000000100199584 0x1000c8000 + 857476
18  APPNAME                     0x00000001001936f4 0x1000c8000 + 833268
19  APPNAME                     0x0000000100194690 0x1000c8000 + 837264
20  UIKit                           0x000000018c75e204 0x18c6dd000 + 528900
21  UIKit                           0x000000018c96a738 0x18c6dd000 + 2676536
22  UIKit                           0x000000018c9701e0 0x18c6dd000 + 2699744
23  UIKit                           0x000000018c984d18 0x18c6dd000 + 2784536
24  UIKit                           0x000000018c96d474 0x18c6dd000 + 2688116
25  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018816b884 0x188131000 + 239748
26  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018816b6f0 0x188131000 + 239344
27  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018816baa0 0x188131000 + 240288
28  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018657142c 0x186496000 + 898092
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186570d9c 0x186496000 + 896412
30  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018656e9a8 0x186496000 + 887208
31  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018649eda4 0x186496000 + 36260
32  UIKit                           0x000000018c757384 0x18c6dd000 + 500612
33  UIKit                           0x000000018c752058 0x18c6dd000 + 479320
34  APPNAME                     0x00000001001a2a98 0x1000c8000 + 895640
35  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001854ad59c 0x1854a9000 + 17820

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185682ca8 0x185682000 + 3240

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018559f224 0x18559e000 + 4644
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018559f09c 0x18559e000 + 4252
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000186570e90 0x186496000 + 896656
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018656eae4 0x186496000 + 887524
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018649eda4 0x186496000 + 36260
5   Foundation                      0x0000000186fb8d74 0x186fac000 + 52596
6   Foundation                      0x0000000186fd9b44 0x186fac000 + 187204
7   UIKit                           0x000000018d0dc6a8 0x18c6dd000 + 10483368
8   Foundation                      0x00000001870b62d8 0x186fac000 + 1090264
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018568568c 0x185682000 + 13964
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018568559c 0x185682000 + 13724
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185682cb4 0x185682000 + 3252

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000010004005   x1: 0x000000000400000e   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000004000
    x4: 0x000000000000680b   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000050
    x8: 0x00000000fffffbbf   x9: 0x000000016fd90000  x10: 0x000000016fd352f0  x11: 0x0000000000000018
   x12: 0x000000016fd352f0  x13: 0x00000000000000d3  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000800000000
   x16: 0xffffffffffffffe1  x17: 0xfffffff2ffffffff  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000000  x21: 0x000000000000680b  x22: 0x0000000000004000  x23: 0x000000016fd312f0
   x24: 0x000000000400000e  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x000000000400000e  x27: 0x00000000fffffefb
   x28: 0x00000000efffbffe   fp: 0x000000016fd312e0   lr: 0x000000018559f09c
    sp: 0x000000016fd31290   pc: 0x000000018559f224 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log. Also, when they say it crashed on a IPv6 network, it doesn't always mean that it's related to an IPv6 network.

Comment: Did you used XMPP Framework?

Comment: @Bali No. I am using Admob.

Comment: enable zombies and check ponce

Comment: Are you making a http call on start up of your app?

Comment: @FangmingNing yes. I am making a HTTPS call on start up of the app

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. Mine was also rejected due to IPV6. Check below two things for your application:

1) Make sure you API link which you used in your application, doesn't have any **ip address**. If you calling API using IPAddress then your application will be rejected.

2) Do testing your application using IPV6 network through your system. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1).

If your application is fullfill both testcase, then don't do any thing, just right comment in iTuneConnect and told them that my application is running in IPV6 network. Can you please guide to find my issue? If possible then can I have a call with your representative?

So they ask your contact detail and give you call and your issue will resvoled. I have wasted around 20 days to solved this issue. But apple representative told that this is them internal issue.

So my humble advice to contact Apple representative as soon as possible and your issue will resolve without doing anything.

Comment: Yes my app is working on ipv6. i have done the same thing that is mentioned in this url: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1

Comment: Then ask Apple representative and get clarification from them. Becuase in case, there is issue from apple side, not from mine. So put comment on resolution center and get connect to them.

Comment: @SudhaTiwari If you symbolicate the crash log as I suggested, meaning make it readable, it may be faster to solve your issue (faster to find where) rather than awaiting for testers answers.

Comment: You can test your application iOS 10.3.2 version. Maybe you will get symbolic crash. But you may wait to get reply from apple representative.

Comment: @Larme I am unable to download the dsym file. It is always showing me "No dSYMs were found for Version 2 Build 1"

Comment: @Nirmalsinh I have tested the build from Testflight on iOS 10.3.2. And it is working fine for me.

Comment: @SudhaTiwari best to solve issue and same time is to connect with them. They will guide in perfect way.